# Searching expect_out(buffer) for hex values

Tags: tcl, expect

I have the following expect script that is supposed to store the expected values into 2 variables hex1 and hex 2.

```
for {set chan 0} {$chan < 6} {incr chan 1} { 
  incr $chan_enable_value 1
  puts $chan_enable_value\r
  send -- "i2c_write -b 0  -r reg -w chan_enable\r"
  expect "barebox: /"
  send -- "i2c_probe\r"
  expect -re "barebox: .* (0x[[:xdigit:]]{2}) (0x[[:xdigit:]]{2})\r\n"
  set hex1 $expect_out(1, string)
  set hex1 $expect_out(2, string)
```

I'm getting the following error when running the script

```
invalid command name ":xdigit:"
```

Comment: So you want to extract standalone numbers like 0x30 but not the ones in ranges like 0x00-0x7f?

Comment: The regular expression `0x[[:xdigit:]]{2}` will be needed, that that will find the "range" numbers as well. Awaiting clarification.

Comment: Note that you need a space between `--` and the command to send. Expect & Tcl (like sh) is very sensitive to whitespace to separate words.

Comment: @glennjackman I edited the script as shown above and I'm getting an invalid command name for "xdigit"

Comment: Addressed in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You *probably* want:

```
  send -- "i2c_probe\r"
  # .....^ note the space
  
  # expect uses \r\n line endings: find 2 space-separated hex numbers at the end of line
  expect -re "barebox: .* (0x[[:xdigit:]]{2}) (0x[[:xdigit:]]{2})\r\n"

  # extract the values captured by the regex parentheses
  set hex1 $expect_out(1,string)
  set hex2 $expect_out(2,string)
  
  puts [list $hex1 $hex2]
```

---

ack, brain fart: square brackets are Tcl's command substitution syntax, and double quotes allow interpolation.

Pick one of

```
  expect -re "barebox: .* (0x\[\[:xdigit:]]{2}) (0x\[\[:xdigit:]]{2})\r\n"
  # .........................^.^...................^.^
```

```
  set regex {barebox: .* (0x[[:xdigit:]]{2}) (0x[[:xdigit:]]{2})}
  expect -re "$regex\r\n"
```

We need to *prevent* interpretation of `[...]` as command substitution but *allow* interpretation of `\r\n`, so it's a bit awkward.